# Expecting a 404 response status code from my Flask application when querying a non existent key in Redis DB - but receiving a 200 code instead

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, flask, redis

I am encountering a test failure in my Python Flask application, where I expect a 404 response status code when querying a non-existent key in my Redis database, but I am consistently receiving a 200 response status code instead. I'm trying to write a Python Flask application to serve as a transparent Redis proxy. Its purpose is to provide an HTTP web service for interacting with the Redis DB. The route handler / code is below :

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import redis 

app = Flask(__name__)

redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host = 'localhost', port=6379, db=0)
@app.route('/get/<key>', methods= ['GET'])
def get_data(key):
    value = redis_client.get(key)
    if value:
        return jsonify({'key': key, 'value': value.decode('utf-8')})
    else:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Key not found'}, 404)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I tried to write some unit tests to verify that it was working correctly :

```
import unittest
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import redis

from redis_proxy import app

class RedisProxyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
    def test_get_data(self):
        redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        redis_client.set('test_key', 'test_value')
        response = self.app.get('/get/test_key')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        expected_data = {'key': 'test_key', 'value': 'test_value'}
        self.assertEqual(response.get_json(), expected_data)

    def test_get_data_key_not_found(self):
        response = self.app.get('/get/xxx')
        print(response.data)
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
        expected_data = {'message': 'Key not found'}
        self.assertEqual(response.get_json(), expected_data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I also added some print statements to print the response data & status code for the branch where the key is present in the database.

Here is the output of these tests:

```
python3 -m unittest redis_proxy_test.py
.b'[{"message":"Key not found"},404]\n'
200
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_data_key_not_found (redis_proxy_test.RedisProxyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/redis-proxy/redis_proxy_test.py", line 26, in test_get_data_key_not_found
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
AssertionError: 200 != 404

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.006s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Also - the key 'xxx' isn't present in the database, so I'm unsure why the status code isn't reflecting that.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GET xxx
(nil)
```

Any ideas as to why this is failing would be really appreciated.

Comment: move the 404 out `jsonify`.  See the example in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/errorhandling/#returning-api-errors-as-json

Answer (score 0):

Change `404` to:

```
return jsonify({'message': 'Key not found'}), 404
```